# SQL Server : select from a table with paging, dynamic column sorting, and dynamic column filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table `Person` with 3 columns `Id`, `FirstName` and `LastName`.

Is it possible to create a stored procedure that contains paging, a dynamic sort columns, and a dynamic filter columns without composing the SQL query with a string and then executing it (`sp_executesql`)?

Params were:

```
page, pageSize, sortColumn, sortOrder, filterColumn, filterSearchString
```

Comment: Try with `INSERT AFTER ` Triggers?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can decide that task without dynamic sql. Try to use such params as id_filter_value, id_sort_value, firstname_filter_value, firstname_sort_value, lastname_filter_value, lastname_sort_value instead of sortColumn, sortOrder, filterColumn, filterSearchString and id_start, id_finish instead of page, pageSize